# Find the count by conditioned group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table on hand:

```
order_id, order_status (2=completed, 1=canceled), client_id, fee
```

I need to find how many client completed 1 order, and how many client completed more than 1 order.

I tried case as below but no clue:

```
select client_id, count(case order_status when '2' then 'completed' end) as cnt_completed, sum(fee)
from order
where cnt_completed = 1;
```

Are there any straightforward ways to get the numbers of clients who completed 1 order and numbers of clients who completed more than 1 order, along with the sum of fee for each group? Thanks.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation to get this broken out by the number of orders:

```
select cnt, count(*), sum(sum_fee)
from (select client_id, count(*) as cnt, sum(fee) as sum_fee
      from order o
      where order_status = '2'
      group by client_id
     ) o
group by cnt;
```

For just two rows, you can use:

```
select (case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 2 end), count(*), sum(sum_fee)
from (select client_id, count(*) as cnt, sum(fee) as sum_fee
      from order o
      where order_status = '2'
      group by client_id
     ) o
group by (case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 2 end);
```

Comment: thank you so much, your solution is very clear, but what does the o means in the code?

Comment: Its a table alias... required for derived tables. And good practice for regular tables.